# Regex: matching "&" only when next to alphanumerical characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, url-parameters

I'm using JavaScript `.split()` to split URL parameters.

Is it possible to use Regex to capture a match of `&` if and only if it exists next to an alphanumerical characters?

Example:

**Not a Match:** `?category=Health+&+Wellness`

**Match:**
`?category=Health&Wellness`

**Doesn't match first, matches second:** `?category=Health+&+Wellness&tag=Diet`

I'm using a script that pulls the parameters out of a URL from a `data-url` attribute in my web template. This is a partial snippet of the parameter script.

```
var query = decodeURIComponent( str ).match( /[#|?].*$/g ),
            ret = {};

        if ( query ) {
            query = query[ 0 ].replace( /^\?|^#|^\/|\/$|\[|\]/g, "" );
            query = query.split( "&" );

            for ( var i = query.length; i--; ) {
                var pair = query[ i ].split( "=" ),
                    key = pair[ 0 ],
                    val = pair[ 1 ];

                if ( ret[ key ] ) {
                    if ( {}.toString.call( ret[ key ] ) !== "[object Array]" ) {
                        ret[ key ] = [ ret[ key ] ];
                    }

                    ret[ key ].push( val );

                } else {
                    ret[ key ] = val;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with my current code is in the `split()` line. Right now it splits parameters like `Health+&+Wellness`, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: `&` symbol is reserved within URI format. You should either urlencode uri's, then `Health & Wellness` will become smth like `?category=Health+%26+Wellness`, or replace it with something else, like `?category=Health+and+Wellness` and convert it back and forth.

Comment: I think you need `/\b&\b/g` (if alphanum and `_` should be on both sides), or `/\b&|&\b/g` (if word characters are only required on one side)

Comment: What if I try this category: `m&m's`?

Comment: That's my current dilemma. My script pulls the parameters out of the URL that I'm using for my AJAX requests and puts them into a data object. The URL is pulled out of my website from a data attribute. Unfortunately for some odd reason I had trouble decoding and encoding. So where I'm at now is that I have a unencoded parameter that I need to work with. I'll edit to add some more of the behind the scenes parameter script.

Comment: Do you have control over whatever generates the URLs? If that is so, you **need** to fix those. The `&` in terms should be URL-encoded (URL-encoding should always be done separately on each component, of course). Additionally, if that ands up in an HTML attribute, it needs to be HTML-attribute-encoded as well (i.e. `&` replaced by `&amp;` etc.).

Comment: 1) `/[#|?].*$/g` must be `/[#?].*$/g`, 2) `/^\?|^#|^\/|\/$|\[|\]/g` must be `/^[?#\/]|\/$|[\][]/g`, and 3) perhaps, `query.split( "&" );` > `query.split(/\b&|&\b/);`.

Comment: `& replaced by &amp; etc.` - I wonder, if that's actual source of problem, like, actually html is `<tag ... data-url="?category=Health+&amp;+Wellness&tag=Diet" .../>` buit it get's extracted as `?category=Health+&+Wellness&tag=Diet` (html-decoded)...

Comment: suggestion: try to `decodeURIComponent( str ).replace(/&([^&=]+(&[^&=]+=|$))/g, '%26$1').match(...`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, preformat uri:

```
var query = decodeURIComponent( str ).replace(/&([^&=]+(&[^&=]+=|$))/, '%26$1');
```

Result:

```
> query = "?category=Health+&+Wellness&tag=Diet"
> query.replace(/&([^&=]+(&[^&=]+=|$))/, '%26$1')
< "?category=Health+%26+Wellness&tag=Diet"
```

*Note: I strongly suggest to debug your code and look how `str` looks like before it is `decodeURIComponent`-ed*

```
> str
< "?category=Health+%26+Wellness&tag=Diet" // no &
> decodeURIComponent(str)
< "?category=Health+&+Wellness&tag=Diet" // & instead of %26
```

So, its possible, that uri conponents must be `decodeURIComponent`-ed **after** uri was split with `split('&')`

Answer (score 0):

Don't call decodeURIComponent on whole string only on key and value after you split:

```
var query = str.match( /[#|?].*$/g ),
        ret = {};

    if ( query ) {
        query = query[ 0 ].replace( /^\?|^#|^\/|\/$|\[|\]/g, "" );
        query = query.split( "&" );

        for ( var i = query.length; i--; ) {
            var pair = query[ i ].split( "=" ),
                key = decodeURIComponent( pair[ 0 ] ),
                val = decodeURIComponent( pair[ 1 ] );

            if ( ret[ key ] ) {
                if ( {}.toString.call( ret[ key ] ) !== "[object Array]" ) {
                    ret[ key ] = [ ret[ key ] ];
                }

                ret[ key ].push( val );

            } else {
                ret[ key ] = val;
            }
        }
    }
```